# In git, how can I remove Windows line endings from changed lines only?

Tags: git, bash

Sometimes when I'm trying to contribute code to an open source project, the project has not been formatted and contains both UNIX and Window line endings. My "smart" IDE will somehow detect which type of ending to use for each file, and if it detects Windows line endings, then all my changes will have Windows line endings (shown as `^M` in `git diff`). How can I remove these Windows line endings from only my changed lines and not the whole file?

Comment: You should figure out what the project standard is, and commit a separate whitespace-only update to the file to get it consistent. If there is no project standard, use Unix line endings. In either case, there's no excuse for having mixed line endings in a single file, let alone over multiple files.

Comment: @miken32, sure but sometimes I don't have time to fix the formatting or the project owners don't want formatting pull requests. In those situations, I just want to get the work done and make sure my changes are consistent.

Comment: Well it takes 15 seconds to strip the offending line endings out and make a second commit; if they don't want it, there's probably some deeper issues with the project!

Comment: Whitespace only commits are incredibly annoying when annotating history.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming your changes are not committed, the following should work:

```
git stash save 'backup-before-removing-windows-line-endings' &&
git stash show -p | perl -pe 's/^([+][^\r]*)\r/$1/g' | git apply - &&
git stash drop
```

#### Explanation:

1. Back up your changes as a stash:

   ```
   git stash save 'backup-before-removing-windows-line-endings'
   ```
2. Output your stashed changes (`git stash show -p`) but remove carriage returns (`\r`) in changed lines (specifically lines beginning with a `+`) using `perl`. Pipe the result to `git apply -` to reapply your changes without carriage returns.

   ```
   git stash show -p | perl -pe 's/^([+][^\r]*)\r/$1/g' | git apply -
   ```
3. If the above commands succeed, delete your backup stash:

   ```
   git stash drop
   ```