# In git, how can I perform a regex replacement on changed lines only?

Tags: git, bash, perl

At first glance, this may seem like a duplicate of [*In git, how can I remove Windows line endings from changed lines only?*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092338/in-git-how-can-i-remove-windows-line-endings-from-changed-lines-only). However, simply adding `^[+]` to the beginning of a pattern will not always work. For example, I recently wanted to change tabs (`\t`) to 4 spaces but only for changed lines. My first instinct was to use the answer from the line endings question but change the regex to this: `perl -pe 's/^[+]\t+/+    /g'`. Unfortunately that will not replace each tab with 4 spaces, but all the leading tabs with 4 spaces total. Is there a solution for this? I can use other CLI tools like `sed` or `awk` if necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is similar to [the answer to the line endings question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36092338/in-git-how-can-i-remove-windows-line-endings-from-changed-lines-only#36092339), but with one key difference for the `perl` one-liner:

```
perl -pe 's/search/replace/flags if /^[+]/'
```

This one-liner will only search and replace one the line if it was added (in other words, it begins with `+`).

Putting that together with the solution from the line endings question, we get:

```
git stash save 'backup-before-replacing-tabs-with-spaces' &&
git stash show -p | perl -pe 's/search/replace/flags if /^[+]/' | git apply - &&
git stash drop
```

For your specific question about replacing tabs with 4 spaces, you would be able to use this straightforward regex: `s/\t/    /g`.

Comment: *"your specific question"* ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
perl -pe 's/^[+](\t+)/"+".("    " x length($1))/e'
```

Replaces a string of one or more tabs with a string that depends on the length of the match.

Comment: Wow, I had no idea that `perl`/regex had that ability. +1 Thanks.